# Is it possible to deallocate memory manually in go?

Tags: go

After discussion with college, I wonder if it would be possible (even if completely does not make any sense) to deallocate memory manually in go (ie. by using unsafe package). Is it?

Comment: No this is not possible.

Comment: You can always deallocate memory you've manually allocated. Is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: The language strives to make you forget about memory management, so it's understandable why they wouldn't have this feature.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a thread that may interest you: [Add runtime.Free() for GOGC=off](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13761)

Interesting part:

> The Go GC does not have the ability to manually deallocate blocks 
>   anymore. And besides, runtime. Free is unsafe (people might free still
>   in use pointers or double free) and then all sorts of C memory problem
>   that Go tries hard to get rid of will come back. The other reason is
>   that runtime sometimes allocates behind your back and there is no way
>   for the program to explicitly free memory.
>
> If you really want to manually manage memory with Go, implement your
>   own memory allocator based on syscall.Mmap or cgo malloc/free.
>
> Disabling GC for extended period of time is generally a bad solution
>   for a concurrent language like Go. And Go's GC will only be better
>   down the road.

**TL;DR: Yes, but don't do it**

Answer (score 5):

I am a bit late but this question is high ranked on google, so here is an article by the creator of DGraph database which explains an alternative to malloc/calloc which is jemalloc, worth a look

https://dgraph.io/blog/post/manual-memory-management-golang-jemalloc/

> With these techniques, we get the best of both worlds: We can do manual memory allocation in critical, memory-bound code paths. At the same time, we can get the benefits of automatic garbage collection in non-critical code paths. Even if you are not comfortable using Cgo or jemalloc, you could apply these techniques on bigger chunks of Go memory, with similar impact.

And I haven't tested it yet, but there is a github library called jemalloc-go

https://github.com/spinlock/jemalloc-go

Edit: Go 1.21 now includes arena. Not useful in every case but gives control over garbage collection in some usecase.

[Medium article about arena](https://medium.com/@metarsit/the-golang-arena-is-here-1aaa7e811e24)